# How could i open multiple connection of DB?

Tags: java, android, database, android-asynctask

I use `Room` Database on android I open the Main Connection on `AsyncTask` on `MainActivity.java`

```
 public AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            AppDatabase.class, "FilmDatabase").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
```

I have another class called `FilmActivity.java` I need to add some data on database on class `FilmActivity.java`

How Can I Do That ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dagger2 to get an instance of your Room database and provide it to all other activities/fragments that may need an instance of it.

Here is a good article using Dagger2 and Room for reference:
https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/integrate-dagger-2-with-room-persistence-library-in-few-lines-abf48328eaeb